# Auto filter to select just the visible rows

Tags: excel, visibility, vba

I have this code. It loops through a list for the filtering criteria, then if no data to select it shows all data again and loops to the next criteria. If it shows data it end(slDown) and selects all the data showing, copies it and pastes it into another worksheet.

The cleanup script cleans any blank rows and columns and then returns to the original data sheet and deletes the data selected for the copy paste.

The problem is when there is just one row. It moves to the row with data, but when I End(xlDown), it shoots all the way to the bottom and the paste then causes the macro to freeze up.

I nested another if statement to capture if there is only one line of data visible, but I cannot get it to function correctly. Any Suggestions on the nested if statement?

```
Dim criteria As String
Dim F As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("Reference").Range("W2:W36")
For Each F In Rng
    criteria = F
    ActiveSheet.Range("$AV$1").AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="=*BULK SUBSERVIENT*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$K$1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=criteria
    Range("A2:CM" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1) _
        .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Else
        If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)) = 2 Then
            'Range(Selection).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Bulk Subservient").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Call cleanup
        Else
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Bulk Subservient").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Call cleanup
    End If
    End If
  Next F
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.... Here is what I did. Thanks all!

I used this If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count <= 2
instead of this (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)) = 2

```
Dim criteria As String
Dim F As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("Reference").Range("W2:W36")
For Each F In Rng
    criteria = F
    ActiveSheet.Range("$AV$1").AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="=*BULK SUBSERVIENT*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$K$1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=criteria
    Range("A2:CM" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1) _
        .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Else
        If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count <= 2 Then
            'Range(Selection).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Bulk Subservient").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Call cleanup
        Else
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Bulk Subservient").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Call cleanup
    End If
    End If
  Next F
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. If you wait 48 hours, you can return and mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be much cleaner than this. I prefer to use an auxiliar funcion to make this filter. Something like this:

```
Function MyFilter(criteria as string) as Range
    Set tableRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  ' Filter 
    With tableRange
        Call .AutoFilter(48, "*BULK SUBSERVIENT*")
        Call .AutoFilter(11, criteria)
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
      'This...
      Set selectedRange = tableRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

      '...Or (how to remover title).
      Set selectedRange = Intersect(tableRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .[2:1000000]) 
    On Error GoTo 0

    With tableRange
        Call .AutoFilter(11)
        Call .AutoFilter(48)
    End With

    'Empty Criteria
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(selectedRange) < 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set MyFilter = selectedRange        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original code rewritten using the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to define the range of cells to be filtered.

```
Dim criteria As String
Dim F As Range, rng As Range

With Worksheets("Reference")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp))
End With

With ActiveSheet    '<~~ set this to worksheets("Sheet1") as appropriate
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        For Each F In rng
            criteria = F
            .AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="*BULK SUBSERVIENT*"
            .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=criteria
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Copy Destination:=Sheets("Bulk Subservient").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                End If
            End With
        Next F
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Here is the same thing that collects all of the criteria terms from the Reference worksheet into a variant array and uses that to filter for all terms at once.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim vCRITERIA As Variant, v As Long

With Worksheets("Reference")
    ReDim vCRITERIA(1 To 1)   '<~~for alternate method
    For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp))
        vCRITERIA(UBound(vCRITERIA)) = rng.Value2
        ReDim Preserve vCRITERIA(UBound(vCRITERIA) + 1)
    Next rng
    ReDim Preserve vCRITERIA(UBound(vCRITERIA) - 1)
End With

With ActiveSheet    '<~~ set this to worksheets("Sheet1") as appropriate
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="*BULK SUBSERVIENT*"
        .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=(vCRITERIA), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .Copy Destination:=Sheets("Bulk Subservient").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        End With
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

The latter is likely a few milli-seconds faster than the first.

The worksheet's [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) never includes filtered or hidden rows so asking for a count will determine if there is anything to copy. Resizing and offsetting moves to the filtered range.

You will need to reincorporate the Cleanup subroutine.